# Records set order by to today's date and time in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to show the records  > today's at top and then all future  records  at bottom. oderby date and time.
"CETTime >= CURTIME()"  need to only show of today's records.

Is there any suggestion do this with single query. ???

I tried this one  but this effect to  "AND CETTime >= CURTIME() "  future recods times as well  , what I need this should be effect only today recods ..

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(`DateofDeparture`, CURDATE()) AS diff   FROM `mytable` 
where DateofDeparture >= CURDATE()  AND
CETTime >= CURTIME() ORDER BY ABS(diff),`CETTime`;
```

```
  AND CETTime >= CURTIME()
```

this  condition  should be effect only today recods time.

[image]

Comment: Please check your question for grammar errors and edit your query, it lacks clarity.

Comment: I am having troubles understanding this, too. Please show five sample rows for the dates 2022-09-26 to 2022-09-30 and show the result you expect to get on 2022-09-28.

Comment: So you don't want to show past days, but you want to show today's past hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the result sample you are showing I conclude:

- you don't want any rows with past dates in the result
- you want today's rows first in ascending order
- you want future rows last in ascending order

Use a `CASE` expression to get today's rows first.

```
select *, datediff(dateofdeparture, curdate()) as diff
from mytable 
where dateofdeparture >= curdate()
order by case when dateofdeparture = curdate() then 1 else 2 end,
         dateofdeparture,
         cettime;
```

If you want past / present / future to depend on *now* rather than *today* then change the `WHERE` clause to

```
where timestamp(dateofdeparture, cettime) >= now()
```

Comment: `where timestamp(dateofdeparture, cettime) >= now()`   @Kettner your where clause suggestion  saved my time.